# How to filter specific datasets by using another dataset?

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements

Im using ms sql-server. By using this base data:

```
CREATE TABLE test(column_1, column_2)
INSERT INTO test
VALUES (1,1),(2,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,3),(3,3),(3,1),(3,1),(3,3),(4,3),(4,1),(5,3),(5,3),(5,3),(6,3),(6,3)
```

Is there a way to select only datasets that have a 3 in column_2, but only if there is another dataset with the same number in column_1 and a 1 in column_2?

So it should look like this in the end:

```
CREATE TABLE result(column_1, column_2)
INSERT INTO test
VALUES (2,3),(2,3),(3,3),(3,3),(3,3),(4,3)
```

Its a combination of these two filters:

1

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE column_2 = 3
ORDER BY column_1
```

2

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_1
FROM table1 
WHERE column_2 = 1
```

I tried putting Query 2 in another column, but I cant use that new column as a condition.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT T2.column_1 WHERE T2.column_2 = 1 ORDER BY T2.column_1) AS colcheck
FROM test T1, test T2
WHERE T1.column_2 = 3 and T2.colcheck = T1.column_1
ORDER BY T1.column_1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will make your desired output:

```
SELECT * FROM Test T1
WHERE 
  column_2 = 3 AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Test WHERE column_1 = T1.column_1 AND column_2 = 1)
ORDER BY 
  column_1
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as a self-join like the other answer, another option is a window aggregate:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        cnt = COUNT(CASE WHEN column_2 = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY column_1)
    FROM test
) t
WHERE column_2 = 3 AND cnt > 0;
```

Comment: thank you for the help. If I understand this logic correctly, the PARTITION gathers all sets that have the same value in column_1 and therefore the CASE checks whether in those datasets a 1 exists in column_2

Comment: Yes. A window aggregate functions like a `GROUP BY` aggregate, except that it doesn't combine rows, the aggregate calculation is applied to all rows in each `PARTITION BY` group